# Quick way to turn layer filter On and Off

Tags: qgis, filter

When a filter is applied to a layer the layer cannot be edited. Is there any way of quickly turning the filter on or off without entering the Query Builder dialog box and removing the filter?

Comment: You can also get around this by using a rule-based renderer, or use a SpatiaLite layer which allows editing while a filter is applied. See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32533/is-it-possible-to-edit-a-layer-in-qgis-while-there-is-an-active-query for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently no but there is a feature request for it (will update when I find it)

Comment: It would be a handy feature to add. Currently it's a little cumbersome, for example if I want to move a label I need to remove the filter, edit, and then reapply the filter. A simple tick box would work, and if it could be attached to the filter selection in the drop down list when right clicking on a layer that would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe play with an URI change (QgsDataSourceURI()).

URI from a shapefile layer is made like this (for example) : `\\MYPATH\MYLAYER.shp|layerid=0|subset="COLUMN" = 'ATTRIBUTE'`

You could imagine the following workflow maybe :

CLICK :

- Get the URI
- Store then remove the end from the pipe sign (|) to the end of the URI
- Reload the datasource

CLICK AGAIN:

- Get the URI
- Add the filter stored previously
- Reload the datasource

I realise it's not the best solution, but it's a try. You could also use the changedatasource plugin to go faster and remove a filter with a right click on the layer.